# System of differential equation of the form $\dot x = (A x) \circ x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am interested in systems of first-order differential equations of the general form $\dot x=(A x) \circ x$, where $A$ is a square, constant, real matrix and $\circ$ is the elementwise product (Hadamard or Schur product). For example, in two dimensions:

$\dot x_1 = (a_{11} x_1 + a_{12} x_2) x_1$

$\dot x_2 = (a_{21} x_1 + a_{22} x_2) x_2$

I have seen these systems arise in various applications, such as in population dynamics, but the pandemic has separated me from my reference books for the time being and I haven't managed to find anything online. Do these systems have a name and/or general analytical tools associated with them?

There are some constraints on the matrix entries, coming from the fact that it must preserve $\sum_i x_i = 1$.